# Career changing from ME to CS

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding

I have a 4 year bachelor of engineering in Mechanical. I want to do Msc phd in CS( Computer Science). How can I get any kind of funding (TA / RA / Schoolarship) in USA/Canada  when i dont have any kind of academic certification in CS. I have a long experience in building softwares in C++,Win32,Java,Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Ph.D. granting schools are open to students that are coming from a different field, especially if they can show that they do not need to start from scratch. In the good schools, CS graduate programs will support their students, first with a limited time (like two year) scholarship. Giving you a T.A. ship would be difficult because you still need to get knowledge of the majority of the courses, but is not impossible, as you can T.A. classes like Discrete Mathematics if it is offered by the CS department.

In your case, it might be worth-while to do well on the GRE Subject test as it assess your background in CS, even if it is not required by the institution.

Comment: I'd guess they could TA CS1 (Intro to programming). They might need to sit some of the lectures, though.

Comment: Is it a wise decision to do a msc program in home country for certificate sake :)(they take one semester to teach elementary cs course like discrete algo data structure network etc) and rest 2 semester for grad subjects(Ai  machine learning etc). And then applying for a phd? I finished mit open learning cs courses(discrete,programing alo data os etc etc) but they dont provide any degree for that.

Comment: I suggest that you apply. A masters isn't necessary in US (not sure about Canada). Don't assume you are unqualified. You can apply in US while also applying for MS in your home country and see what develops.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. Applying both seems good idea now. Thanks a lot.